# DNF conversion of this statement

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How to convert this to DNF?

$(x\lor{\neg{y}\lor{z}})\land{(\neg{x}\lor{\neg{z}})}$

I have tried de morgans and have got no where. I'm pretty sure its the distributive law but cant work out the steps to get in the form to do that.

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE! Can you show your progress so far and where do you get stuck?

Comment: Yes, use distributive law to get the DNF, and apply Consensus theorem to get the Minimal DNF, if you attempted, but still don't get it, please show your work (edit the question) and tell us where you don't understand.

Comment: But in the form its in , I cannot apply the distributive law.

Comment: There are two directions to apply distributive law, if you can't distributive any term out, try distributive in.

Comment: Ah i see, i can just distribute each element on the LHS as its just  a single term all different from the RHS

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of DNF before, looked it up [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form). I take it you just want the simplest boolean out of this.

This is a case that works like distributive multiplication of two sums.

$$(x\lor{\neg{y}\lor{z}})\land{(\neg{x}\lor{\neg{z}})}\\
=x(\neg x\lor \neg z)\lor \neg y(\neg x\lor \neg z)\lor z(\neg x\lor \neg z)\\
=(x\neg x \lor x\neg z)\lor (\neg y\neg x \lor \neg y\neg z)\lor z\neg x \lor z\neg z)\\
$$
If there were no mistakes in this expansion, the Veitch diagram below helps with the solution. For shorthand, a slightly different notation is used. Note that hte conditions $x\neg x$ and $z\neg z$ cannot exist so they are to be ignored.

[image]